# Font Awesome icon increasing div size

Tags: css, html, sass

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div _ngcontent-c1="" class="attach">
   <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="image">
      <img _ngcontent-c1="" id="0" src="...">
    </div>
    <i _ngcontent-c1="" class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</div>
```

With the following scss:

```
.attach {
  display: inline-block;
 i {
    position: relative;
    right: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: .5em;
    color: #efefef;
    background: gray;
    border-radius: 3em;
   }
  .image {
     display: inline-block;
   }
  img {
     z-index: 1;
     border-radius: 1em;
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
    }
 }
.attach:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 filter: brightness(80%);
  i {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

The problem is that the size of the div with class `attach` is being increased [image: image1]

[image]

So, how could I avoid increasing the size of the div?

Comment: The div with the `attach`-class will increase in size to fit its content. I can't really figure out what you want to do instead from your question. I expect that creating an absolute positioned div and/or a change the html structure would solve it.

Comment: You can try setting the icon to be position absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone has the same error, I solved it putting the image as `background-image` of the div, and the following rules:

```
background-size: cover;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
text-align: center;
```

Then it is just a matter of centering the font awesome icon in the middle of your div using `position: relative` and the proper percentages.